# Переместить вывод $title

Tags: drupal, tpl

Есть тип контента с полем image, и форматтером bxslider.
У этого слайдера 2 tpl.php: bxslider.tpl.php и bxslider_ths.tpl.php

Надо $title ноды переместить так, чтобы он выводился не в вершине страницы, а блоком внутри слайдера. Просто переместить код, например этот:

```
                    <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
                    <?php if ($title):?>
                    <h1 class="page-title"><?php print $title; ?></h1>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
```

результата не дает. Как это сделать?

bxslider_ths.tpl.php

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Template for BxSlider.
 */
?>
<div id="<?php print $slider_id; ?>">
  <ul class="bxslider" style="display:none">
    <?php foreach($items as $item): ?>
      <li><?php print $item['slide']; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
  <ul class="bxslider-ths" style="display:none">
    <?php foreach($thumbnail_items as $key => $thumbnail_item): ?>
      <li slideindex="<?php print $key ?>"><a href="#"><?php print $thumbnail_item['thumbnail']; ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
</div>?>
```

и bxslider.tpl.php

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Template for BxSlider.
 */
?>
<div id="<?php print $slider_id; ?>">
  <ul class="bxslider" style="display:none">
    <?php foreach($items as $item): ?>
      <li><?php print $item['slide']; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>

  <?php if(isset($settings['slider_settings']['pagerCustom_type']) && $settings['slider_settings']['pagerCustom_type'] == 'thumbnail_pager_method1'): ?>
    <div id="<?php  print $settings['slider_settings']['pagerCustom'] ?>">
      <?php foreach($items as $key => $item): ?>
        <a data-slide-index="<?php print $key ?>" href=""><?php print $item['slide_pagerCustom']; ?></a>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>?>
```

Comment: А через [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) не пробовали?

Comment: а слайдер что только картинку выводит без всяких надписей?